# I want to block iframe ads

Tags: php, web, iframe, adblock

I have a website built using php which has several iframe links in their codes. But the websites of the iframe shows annoying ads which demonetize my website.
Is there any option to block these iframe ads from the server side? I dont want any ads on my website and I dont want that my viewers put up a hassle to install adblockers on the client side.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, i need to reply to that answer too actually... Can sandbox elements be used to block them. Read an article about it

Comment: That's not what your question asked but what you want to achieve would probably break some rules in terms of moral (as minimum). If you want to filter content server side, you should first process the iframe url from a specific route on your server, that will return the processed response and will be called by the action rendering the final response including the iframe and its content. But you'll be soon contacted by that web site for violating its terms of use. If you don't want to serve its ads you shouldn't serve its contents

Answer (score 1):

Content in an iframe is loaded directly from the URL the iframe points to, into the user's browser. It does not go via your server.

So it's up to the user to choose whether to try and block ads, or up to you to decide not to embed those sites within yours any more.

Comment: Can sandbox elements be used to block them. Read an article about it

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "sandbox elements" please